# Export structure only for testing in Golang

Tags: go

I have a utility package that many other packages use. I also created some test structures that implement those interfaces. And I put them in `interfaces_test.go`

I'd like to be able to import those test structures in other packages in my `*_test.go` files.

I saw something like that in http://golang.org/src/pkg/os/export_test.go but whatever I try I get an error similar to this one:

```
go test something/mypackage
mypackage/ant_lat_lon_test.go:46: undefined: rutl.TestAntenner
FAIL    something/mypackage [build failed]
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Files matching `*_test.go` are only compiled when testing the package they are part of.  If you are testing package A that uses package B, you won't have access to the `_test.go` code from package B.

So the two options are:

1. Always compile the test support code into package B.
2. If the test support code only depends on the exported interface of B, consider splitting it out into a separate package.

Comment: If you always compile the test structures into package B, will they be dropped by the linker in the production executable?

Comment: @DonGar no, the testing package will be included in your final binary. This will ruin your command line, for example.

Comment: @hraban: are you sure about that?  Unreferenced code are usually omitted from the final executable (e.g. using a single function from a large package does not imply the entire package will end up in your executable).

Comment: @JamesHenstridge I am sure that the command line is hooked into using flag; test this yourself by importing testing and passing `-h` to your resulting binary. There may be completely unreferenced parts of the testing library which end up not being included, but it will always be at least partially included. Enough to be annoying.

Comment: @hraban: I wasn't suggesting that you put `import "testing"` into the package's non testing files. The question seemed to be talking about wanting to export some fake/mock implementations of an interface for use by tests in other packages, and that kind of thing should just get omitted by the linker if it isn't actually referenced by the executable.

Comment: My bad, I thought you meant including the testing package itself. I happened upon this question because I am struggling with a mock generating library which does precisely that, just now, hence my assumption. Sorry for the confusion :)

Comment: Yes, I was worried about exporting Mock/Fake structures. I also expect the linker to drop them if they are never referenced in non-test code. The ability to do so should be one of the advantages of Go's static linking.